# longtable spanning multicolumns

Tags: page-breaking, two-column, longtable

How to use make a `longtable` span across a two-column document?

I'm working on a `twocolumn` class, and I'd like to make the `longtable` be centralized in the page, as well as to make the orphan items, i.e. last items that shows up in a separate (last, usually) page to follow the same pattern as the initial pages.

I've thought about a similar way as the use of `\begin{table*}`, but I couldn't figure out how to do that for `longtable`.

I'd really appreciate to hear some experience on that.

Comment: I think the only way to do this will be with alternating `multicolumn` and `longtable`. Could you give some example code which could be used as a basis for a solution? It doesn't have to work, just to show what you are getting at.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind the table starting a new page then you can do

```
  \onecolumn
  \begin{longtable}....
  .....
  \end{longtable}
  \twocolumn
```

If that doesn't do what you need then probably you need to edit your question to add a complete but small example and say more exactly what you want it to produce.